# Ways for database connectivity in HTML website which should support in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing E-Commerce website in HTML, for that i want to store product information like ProductName, Price, Brand etc in database.

I was tried with ActiveXObject using JavaScript for Sql Database, but it works only in IE, and i know it doesn't support in other browsers directly.

So tell me any alternative way for DB connectivity in HTML which supports in all popular browsers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a database on your server directly from HTML/Javascript. You need something like PHP, ASP, Coldfusion, CGI etc. on your server to query the database, generate HTML from the query result and send it to the client.

For more dynamic webpages you can use AJAX to send a request to the server. On the server side the request will be processed by PHP, ASP, Coldfusion, CGI etc. with the result sent back to the client, where you can dynamically change the webpage through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 [web storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/) and [Client Side Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/). I think latest versions of Chrome, Safari, FireFox and IE supports HTML5 Local Storage..